# Is it possible to disable keys in C++?

Tags: c++, user-input

I was just wondering whether it was possible to disable keys (such as the alphabet and other characters), so that the user could not input them into integers and cause errors. If it's not possible (or recommended), could you please let me know how to handle the errors?

Comment: Why don't you just handle the errors?  In your current situation, the easy answer may seem like "hey, if I just disable these keys, they CAN'T give improper input, so I won't have an error!" but if you keep programming, there will be a time when you have to allow all the keys, but improper input could still come.

Comment: Sorry, if it's not a great question. I'm kind of new to C++, so would you mind letting me know how to do that?

Comment: If you edit your question to actually ask how to handle input errors when you're asking user to input an integer, I'll post an answer.

Comment: As always: if you want fine grained control on user input write a GUI application. In a console application, just be ready to handle invalid data that the user may enter.

Answer (score 1):

```
int x;
std::cout << "Enter a number: ";
std::cin >> x;
while(std::cin.fail())
{
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n');
    std::cout << "Bad entry.  Enter a NUMBER: ";
    std::cin >> x;
}
std::cout << "x = " << x << "\n";

std::system("pause");
return 0;
```

This will stay in the `while` loop until the user enters a valid integer.  You can put more checks to make sure the number the user enters is with a certain range, or add variables to allow a certain number of guesses, etc.

And of course, you'll want to edit prompts and stuff to tailor this to whatever you're using it for, but you can create a new project load this file in and test it out to see how it works.  Play with this a bit and now you know how to do some basic user input handling.

Moreover, you can change `x` in this template to a `double` and this still works perfectly fine.  If you were to "turn off keys", then you have to decide whether a key like `-` (negative sign) or `.` (decimal) should be allowed or not.

Comment: Thanks, but what how could you also restrict decimal numbers?

Comment: Changing `x` to a `float` or `double` should still allow this to work.

Answer (score 0):

What you want here, is definitely NOT to disable some keys on the keyboard. However, once the key is pressed and the character is sent, you can compare it. For example, you could remove the last input if it fails a specific test:

```
bool validChar(const char &c) {
    return (c >= '0' && c <= '9');
}
```

Then, you really should test the final input to ensure that the user hasn't found a way to send a non-integer value.

Comment: This is just the easy part, what is more  tricky is integrating it with the rest of the streams machinery. Incidentally, there's no point in passing a single char by const reference.

Comment: You are right. I didn't know if it was required inside of a console or GUI application. The other answer is probably easier to implement and maintain. For the const reference, it's only been a safe way for me to ensure that nothing and no one can change an argument inside the function.

Comment: With primitive types normally you just pass arguments by value.